# Is it possible to work in Appen just using Android? because at the moment we don't have a laptop but we really want to join the project from Appen

Tags: android, facebook, instagram, telegram, siamese-network

Can the Appen project be done using only Android? I really hope I can because I don't have a laptop yet and really want to join the APPEN project

Please help with an explanation regarding working on Appen projects using only Android